# Pandas data frame problem. 1st is as input and 2nd image would be output or result

Tags: pandas

Working with pandas data frame. How Can I separate Scope and its value in new Type columns and value is added in various row. Please see the 1st iamge

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all columns are ordered in pairs is possible filter even and odd columns and recreate DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Verified By':df.iloc[:, 1::2].stack(dropna=False).to_numpy(),
                  'tCO2':df.iloc[:, ::2].stack(dropna=False).to_numpy()})
print (df1)
    Verified By       tCO2
0  Cventure LLC     12.915
1  Cventure LLC     61.801
2           NaN     78.551
3           NaN      5.712
4           NaN     49.513
5  Cventure LLC     24.063
6  Carbon Trust    679.000
7           NaN      4.445
8  Cventure LLC  56290.000
```

Another idea is split by first 2 spaces and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(n=2, expand=True)

df1 = df.stack([0,1]).droplevel(0)
df1.index = df1.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}')
df1 = df1.rename_axis('Score').reset_index()
print (df1)
     Score   Verified By       tCO2
0  Scope 1  Cventure LLC     12.915
1  Scope 2  Cventure LLC     61.801
2  Scope 3           NaN     78.551
3  Scope 1           NaN      5.712
4  Scope 2           NaN     49.513
5  Scope 3  Cventure LLC     24.063
6  Scope 1  Carbon Trust    679.000
7  Scope 2           NaN      4.445
8  Scope 3  Cventure LLC  56290.000
```